# Why in a periodic system the electric field is eigenvector of the translation operator

Tags: electromagnetism

I would like to know why in a classical periodic system (I am not doing quantum physics), the electric field has to be an eigenvector of the translation operator associated to the periodicity ?

Comment: This will be easier to answer if you provide a more specific reference of this happening. In general, the field does not need to be an eigenvector of the symmetry operator; it's simply more convenient. However, there are situations (particularly when there is a specific periodic driving) where the periodic solution is the only one of interest. Without knowing which situation you're in, this is hard to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In my course it is presented as a general result, but I can give you a context :

You have a 1D material with Epsilon relative that is a-periodic.

Then you have the electric field that will be an eigenvector of the translation operator with "a" parameter.

Comment: Unless you're leaving something out, it seems that all your book is saying is the obvious: the field is periodic. If you translate the field in the system down by $a$ then you have the same field, so the field is an eigenvector of the $a$-translation operator.

Comment: But the field is not periodic.
Because the eigenvalue is a complex exponential.

So when I translate the field from "a", I will have the same field WITH a difference a phase "phi".

So that's not obvious and I don't understand why.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the physical system you're considering, but the absolute phase cannot have any physical significance, only relative phase. If you translate and pick up a complex phase, you are free to multiply the field everywhere by a global (and physically irrelevant) phase to get the same field you had before the translation.